# Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded In Single Level If Statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function which I would like to check and see what type of request is being used and then run another function based on which one is chosen.

```
     from tests.global_functions.util_helper import util_get_random_customer_individual
     from tests.global_functions.util_helper import util_get_random_customer_company
     import requests

     def __init__(self):
        request = requests.Requests()
        if request == requests.Requests().data_add_customer_individual():
            customer = util_get_random_customer_individual()
        else:
            customer = util_get_random_customer_company()
```

When I try to run this, I am getting `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

If I change `import requests` to `from requests import Requests` I get an error saying that it cannot import requests

What am I doing incorrectly?

I tried doing the following:

```
        request = requests.Requests
        if request == requests.Requests.data_add_customer_individual():
           customer = util_get_random_customer_individual()
        else:
           customer = util_get_random_customer_company()
```

and I am still getting the recursion depth exceeded error.

Here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\e003048\QA\trunk\automation\selenium\src\webservices\system_environment\customer.py", line 26, in __init__
    if request == requests.Requests.data_add_customer_individual():
File "C:\Users\e003048\QA\trunk\automation\selenium\src\webservices\system_environment\requests.py", line 85, in data_add_customer_individual
    my_request = request_data.RequestData()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was calling my own variable over and over it was causing the max recursion error. To fix this I added a variable to my `Requests()` class called `request_type = None` then in my `add_customer_individual` function I declared the `request_type = 'individual' and the same for the`add_customer_company` function only naming the request type company.

Then in  my customer class I did the following:

```
    request = Requests()
    if request.request_type == 'individual':
        customer = util_get_random_customer_individual()
    elif request.request_type == 'company':
        customer = util_get_random_customer_company()
    else:
        print 'What the hell should I do???? HELP!?!?!?!'
```

This should work as soon as I find out why I cannot use `from requests import Requests

Comment: can you perhaps provide more information so we can help, instead of guessing wildly

Answer (score 2):

By any chance is this class called `Requests`, and does it live in a module named `requests`?  It looks a lot like you're creating a new object within the class's own constructor.  The line shown in your traceback will tell you for sure.

Comment: yes there is a module called requests with a class called Requests

Comment: @DarthOpto: why do you call `requests.Requests()` inside `requests.Requests.__init__()` method?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am not inside the requests _init_() method I am inside a customer _init_() method

Comment: in that case it's very hard to tell what's going on without any of the current filename, the class name, the traceback, or the code being called

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the call you are making to `data_add_customer_individual` results in a new object of your current class being created (since you have cut out the `class` statement I don't know what that is called). This results in recursive object creation, as the new object will also call `data_add_customer_individual`, which will create another new object, etc.

Here's a small example that does the same thing:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        Bar()

def bar():
    foo = Foo() # create a new Foo instance
    print foo   # this won't ever get reached, since the recursion happens above
```

Usually a way to fix this kind of recursion is to pass an instance of the `Foo` object through to `bar`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        bar(self) # pass ourself as a reference!

def bar(foo):  # bar now takes foo as a parameter, rather than creating it
    print foo  # this will work
```